# how to achieve table that each column data is distinct?

Tags: sql-server

I guess my example is not clear.
table is: :

```
 
id - name   -    work
-------------------------
```

```
1 - sina    -     programmer

2 - ali     -     programmer 
3 - jack    -     graphist    
4 - sina    -     graphist
```

---

i want to have  below result that each column data is distinct.Suppose the columns in result table are independent:

```
id - name   -    work
 
-------------------------
1  - sina   -     graphist

2  - ali    -     programmer

3  - jack   -
```

---

tanks

Comment: That's really not how SQL works, or at least is meant to work. The columns within each *row* are meant to represent different attributes belonging to a single "entity".

Comment: So... you want to select distinct values in `name`, distinct values in `number`, and then put them into the same table. Is order important?

Comment: That's a lot of downvotes considering there's no feedback.

Comment: Your question reminds me [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196194/selecting-distinct-values-for-multiple-columns) very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hi guys
this solution is my answer :

With CTE1 as  
(select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [name] order by id) as rn1 from @TAB )
,CTE2 as
(select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [work] order by id desc) as rn2 from @TAB )
select C1.Id,C1.[name],ISNULL(C2.[work],'') from CTE1 C1 left join CTE2 C2
on C1.rn1=1 and C2.rn2=1 and C1.[name]=C2.[name]
where C1.rn1=1
order by C1.id
---------OUPUT------------
--1 sina graphist
--2 ali programmer
--3 jack
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
WITH names_CTE (Name, RowNum)
                AS
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT Person.Name,
                    ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY Name) RowNum
                    FROM Person
                )
                SELECT * FROM JBAccount_CTE cte
```

In this way each name will have a different number.

Comment: It doesn't achieve what the OP asked for though.

Comment: It seems that the number column is not relevant, since in the second code portion, he assigns "2" to "Ali" name. While in the first portion Ali was assigned to 1 and 3.

Therefore selecting just the names (with DISTINCT statement) I am sure to have unique names and unique numbers given by Row_Number().
I intended in this way his request...

Comment: But you're assuming that the numbers will start from 1 and be sequential, which is not what has been asked for.