# Take duplicated values of different columns in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, duplicates, multiple-columns

How do I take duplicated values of different columns in the same table?

I think that is simple. I have got a table:

```
Id    Column1     Column2
-------------------------
 1    John        red
 2    Patrick     white
 3    Alessia     yellow
 4    Aline       red
 5    Eva         orange
 6    John        blue
 7    Oscar       yellow
 8    Peter       red
```

So, the result I want is this:

```
Column1     Column2    Total1  Total2
-------------------------------------
John        red           2      3
Patrick     yellow        1      2
Alessia     white         1      1
Aline       orange        1      1
Eva         blue          1      1
Oscar                     1
Peter                     1
```

So: to take the duplicates, sum and group them and order them.

I can do it only with one column like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5
  column1, COUNT(*) AS total1
FROM table
GROUP BY column1
ORDER BY total1 DESC
```

But it's impossible to do with more than one column. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: You have 4 values for `ID`, but 6 for `Column1` and even 8 for `Column2` - how does this work? Can you show your table data in a tabular format? Just indent your lines by at least 4 characters to properly format those lines!

Comment: Sorry!!! Edited.
Now 8 values!

thanks!

Comment: What you're trying to do is highly confusing and quite honestly really doesn't make any sense ... you should get **one output** that counts `Column1` (names) and their number of occurrences, and a **second, independent** output that counts `Column2` and their number of occurrences. Trying to squeeze all of this into a single output (a) doesn't make sense, and (b) is very confusing to read and understand, and (c) cannot be easily done in SQL either.....

Comment: You have John red and John blue. But in output there is only one John. What happen to blue John. I think you need to revise your examples and requirements. What you are asking is not possible and not what databases are used for. And yes, it does not make any sense.

Comment: As a matter of fact, this question, even if in a simpler form, has already been asked. If you really need to do this in one query, you could try using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196194/selecting-distinct-values-for-multiple-columns/5197909#5197909 "Selecting distinct values for multiple columns") as a starting point. Perhaps you would only need to throw in a `COUNT(*) OVER ...` per every column that you need the distinct value set of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for a general mechanism to combine the two relations (Name, CountOfColorForName) and (Color, CountOfNameForColor) into a single relation. There is no GENERAL way to do this; a application-specific mapping is required first. Given this mapping, the appropriate SQL can be written trivially.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I think i am going to do different statements