# SQL Duplicate Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and was wondering if anyone could help me solve my problem.
I have a table that contains information as follows:

```
firstname lastname  group   orderinggroup    date 
tim          s        A          Facebook    6/4/13
tim          s        A          Facebook    6/4/13
tim          s        A          Facebook    6/4/13
dan          d        B          Google      4/5/12
dan          d        B          Google      4/5/12
```

Something like that. I want it to look like this

```
firstname lastname  group   orderinggroup    date 
  tim          s        A          Facebook    6/4/13
  dan          d        B          Google      4/5/12
```

Where there aren't duplicates for tim and dan. I tried using DISTINCT but that only makes one column distinct, and I actually have many people named Tim, Dan, Groups that are A/B, etc. I was wondering if there is a method to take the distinct of multiple roles, e.g., Distinct of firstname, lastname, group, orderinggroup, and date. Last names matter. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server ?

Comment: the answer is correct, you experiment it and google group by syntax

Comment: I am using a Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: could you limit only 1 Tim for your system. 2nd guy, "We already have a Tim"

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this: [Selecting distinct values for multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196194/selecting-distinct-values-for-multiple-columns)?

Answer (score 0):

You could really use the max() function to aggregate some of the columns and do something like this:

```
select 
     firstname, 
     lastname, 
     [group], 
     max(orderinggroup) as orderinggroup, 
     max([date]) as [date] 
from (VALUES
('tim','s','A','Facebook','6/4/13'),
('tim','s','A','Facebook','6/4/13'),
('tim','s','A','Facebook','6/4/13'),
('dan','d','B','Google','4/5/12'),
('dan','d','B','Google','4/5/12')) as A (firstname,lastname,[group],orderinggroup,[date])  
--replace this with your tablename  
GROUP BY firstname, lastname, [group]
ORDER BY [group]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bad data and DISTINCT will work. DISTINCT is actually great for this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from table
```

Why even list columns unless there is direct manipulation or subqueries going on? There's not even a JOIN in your statement. Please tell me with a comment why DISTINCT does not work in this situation as you mention you've used it before.

DISTINCT checks each column for matching values, if it hits a value that doesn't match on record A from record B it will spit out record B also because it's distinct from A. Even if everything before it matches.

In your example:

```
firstname lastname  group   orderinggroup    date 
tim          s        A          Facebook    6/4/13
tim          s        A          Facebook    6/4/13
tim          s        A          Facebook    6/4/13
dan          d        B          Google      4/5/12
dan          d        B          Google      4/5/12
```

Let's start with Tim. Every field is exactly the same. Therefore Distinct would collapse all these records into one row. Same for Dan. Now if the lastname is different in your actual database (which should be reflected in your example) then DISTINCT will not work. However, the premise of your question would need to change. You would need to discern what in fact you want to reflect in your data set. Do you want to ignore the last name? Do you want to consider it? These questions are pertinent. Group By works also, but is unnecessary as you're not doing aggregates. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You can use below query:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, group, orderinggroup, date
FROM tablename
GROUP BY firstname, lastname, group, orderinggroup, date
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? I tried doing stuff like DISTINCT firstname, lastname, group etc. but it only gives the distinct of firstname. Keep in mind that my database is 4k+ and we have lots of people with the first name of tim

Comment: Using GROUP BY  with all the fields should solve your problem. Try the updated query.

Comment: The HAVING doesn't make sense here

Comment: I concur! `HAVING` wouldn't be necessary for this. Also, it wouldn't make much sense to use `Group By`  if you are including all columns.

Comment: Because of `GROUP BY` with all fields, only one distinct column will come of respective column.